# How to add a data resource within a Terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a data resource and module like

```html
data "aws_instances" "XXX" {
  instance_tags = {
    Name = "XXXX"
  }
  instance_state_names = ["running", "stopped"]
}


module "XXXX" {
  count = length(data.aws_instances.ids)

  source   = "./alarms"
  id       = data.aws_instances.ids[count.index]

}
```

How can I move the data block inside the module

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that?

Data source is a kind of resource.

If you want to use some data out of data source use syntax:
data.aws_instances.xxxxx

See [terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources) for that.